# NextJS shows Warning: Prop className did not match when using Tailwind CSS and styled components

Tags: next.js, styled-components

```
import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export const CartContext = createContext({});

export function CardContextProvider({ children }) {
  const [cartProducts, setCartProducts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      const localStorageData = window.localStorage.getItem('cartProducts');
      if (localStorageData) {
        setCartProducts(JSON.parse(localStorageData));
      }
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      window.localStorage.setItem('cartProducts', JSON.stringify(cartProducts));
    }
  }, [cartProducts]);

  function addProduct(productId) {
    setCartProducts([...cartProducts, productId]);
  }

  function removeProduct(productId) {
    const index = cartProducts.findIndex((id) => id === productId);
    if (index !== -1) {
      const newCartProducts = [...cartProducts];
      newCartProducts.splice(index, 1);
      setCartProducts(newCartProducts);
    }
  }

  return (
    <CartContext.Provider value={{ cartProducts, setCartProducts, addProduct, removeProduct }}>
      {children}
    </CartContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

[image]

What can cause this warning? I tried to avoid all things presented [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error) and I am still encountering this error. I am using next.js, tailwind and styled components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem :**

> *Nextjs hydration :  cannot write a title without error*

**Possible Cause :**

- Browser Extensions
- Using browser-only APIs like window or localStorage in your rendering logic & not using 'use client' directive
- Improper `next.config.js`

**Possible Solution :**

- Add 'use client' directive at top of file in `CardContextProvider`
- Disable all browser extensions,

**Add `styledComponents: true,` in `next.config.js` :**

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const nextConfig = {
  ...
  compiler: {
    styledComponents: true,
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

**Please Read :**

- **'use client'** : https://react.dev/reference/react/use-client
- **Example app with styled-components** : https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-styled-components
- **With SWC**: https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#next.js
- **If using App router in NextJS** : https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#app-directory

> ***If you have any doubts, then please leave a comment (I will update answer if necessary)***

Comment: the step with next.config.js solved my problem.Thank you

Comment: @Renato then you may accept this answer.